# How does Shri Shankar's Advaita answer Shri Ramanuja's Tirodhan-Anuppatti?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, ramanujacharya

The second argument of Shri Ramanuja over Shri Shankar's Advaita is Tirodhan-Anuppatti. How does Avidya Maya, who is dependent on Brahman, envelope Brahman. Advaitains say that Maya is dependent on Brahman, just as magic is dependent on Magician, so, Can a magician's trick confound the Magician himself?
Please answer with examples.

Comment: I think you meant argument and not what you wrote?